# Using a Ternary Conditional with in Asp.Net MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to get the following ternary conditional to work in Asp.Net MVC 3 Razor:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("TestBrowse", new { page = @(Model.IsLastPage ? Model.PageNumber : Model.PageNumber + 1) })">Next</a>
```

All of the examples I am finding of using a ternary conditional in Razor have return values which are strings.  But here I would like to use an expression (Model.PageNumber + 1) and return a number.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the @ sign before the value:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("TestBrowse", new { page = Model.IsLastPage ? Model.PageNumber : (Model.PageNumber + 1) })">Next</a>
```

Let me just add that in general, Razor doesn't need/want the `@` prefix unless it's absolutely necessary, for example:

```
<div>
@foreach(var value in Model.Values)
{
if(value.Flag)
{
<div>@value.Text</div>
}
}
<div>
```

Notice that you don't need a second `@` sign until you're actually inside the  tag, where Razor wouldn't know whether you wanted to display the text "value.Text" or execute it as code. The `if` statement is assumed to be code. To escape this and write the line "if(value.Flag)" as text you'd need to explicitly say so with the `@:` prefix.

Comment: That worked.  And thanks for the added insights into using Razor. Very helpful.